# Axios get giving undefined

Tags: javascript, axios, string-interpolation

I am facing a strange issue with respect to axios get call.

```
try {
        console.log('assetAddress', assetAddress);
        var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v1/events?only_opensea=false&limit=20&asset_contract_address=${assetAddress}`,
            headers: { "Accept": 'application/json' }
        };
        console.log(options.url)
        res = await axios.request(options);
        return res.data;
    } catch (e) {
        //console.log(e)
    }
```

When I pass assetAddress in the url and then try to get the result it is showing undefined. But when I hardcode the assetAddress with my actual 0x15352F80426ec9b94412b45242d7040b5dFeB5E6.

Why this happens any clue?

Comment: Maybe there is a newline, or something in the string? You could try using `assetAddress.trim()`.

Comment: Also, are you sure that `assetAddress` is not actually `undefined`? Are you making this request in the browser? If so, please open the dev tools and look, what the networking tab says the final url is.

Comment: I have tried trim() but no use same issue. Yes I am doing a console.log just before the url construction the assetAddress has value it is not undefined.

Comment: No I am not running this on any browser, running this in aws bean stack.

Comment: Seems to me like the question lacks some context. I am not sure that the error is located in the shown code.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the scope of your `assetAddress` variable is the problem here.

Here are 2 examples using 2 different versions

---

You can use the `.then` and `.catch` function instead of using `async / await` here

```js
const assetAddress = "0x15352F80426ec9b94412b45242d7040b5dFeB5E6"

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: `https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v1/events?only_opensea=false&limit=20&asset_contract_address=${assetAddress}`,
  headers: {
    "Accept": 'application/json'
  }
};
axios.request(options)
  .then(res => console.log(res.data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.0.0-alpha.1/axios.min.js"></script>
```

---

Here is the version if you still wants to use the classic version.

```js
const assetAddress = "0x15352F80426ec9b94412b45242d7040b5dFeB5E6"

async function loadData() {
  console.log("Loading Data")
  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: `https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v1/events?only_opensea=false&limit=20&asset_contract_address=${assetAddress}`,
    headers: {
      "Accept": 'application/json'
    }
  };
  try {
    const res = await axios.request(options)
    console.log(res)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

document.getElementById('loadDataButton').addEventListener('click', loadData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.0.0-alpha.1/axios.min.js"></script>

<button id="loadDataButton">Load data</button>
```

Comment: But I want return the axios get result to another called function. How can i do that?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Check your definition of the `assetAddress` variable imo

Comment: @Renaud5 Thanks for your answer. I have changed as per your answer but I am facing same issue.(get axios data is undefined)

Comment: Can you please update your answer and add more details as where is define `assetAddress` or the global axios call